# Does Maui Hot Reload Work When you pair a Mac from Windows

Tags: maui, maui-windows

I have a .NET MAUI app.  When I compile it in Visual Studio Mac iOS, it gives me errors about Microsoft.IOS being too high of a version.  Microsoft.IOS is a nuget package, but I can not downgrade it.  So, I changed Linker settings to SDK Only and I was able to run my MAUI app in Visual Studio Mac.  Even in VS Code, my MAUI application ran on the Mac.

My problem is that with Linker settings to SDK Only, I can not use Hot Reload in Visual Studio Mac, and in VS Code Mac, I am unable to use Hot Reload.  In VS Code, I tried using .NET Watcher, but no Hot Reload.

If I run my MAUI app in Windows, using the pair to Mac feature, will I be able to use Hot Reload?

Comment: Is your development tool the latest version? Also describe your problem in detail, Please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

[minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)